# reactjs redux form passing Onclick function to a field

Tags: reactjs, redux, onclick, react-redux, redux-form

i have the following

```
const Range = field => {
  <Button
    className="btn btn-info plus_btn"
    onClick={() => {
      field.handleClick();
    }}
  />;
};

const component = (props: { dismiss: Function }) => {
  <Field
    name="Test"
    component={Range}
    props={props}
    label="Test"
    handleClick={() => console.log("Clicked!")}
  />;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Function) => ({
  dismiss: () => {
    console.log("dismiss");
  }
});
```

when i press on the button it gives me handleclick is not a function, i want to to pass dismiss function to the handleclick function so that when i click on the button inside Range it calls dismiss function in mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: I have never used such `const component = (props: {
  dismiss: Function,
}) => {` does this work? It would be new finding for me. Any reference?

Comment: this is a normal functional component. https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: not able to find such params

Comment: `console.log(field)` from within the `Range` and post what it contains

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use it in the Range Component

```
const Range = field => {
  <Button
    className="btn btn-info plus_btn"
    onClick={() => {
      field.dismiss();
    }}
  />;
};
```

Otherwise, if you want to pass a handleClick function to the Range Component you need to pass it in the props of the Field of reduxforms like this:

```
const Range = field => {
  <Button
    className="btn btn-info plus_btn"
    onClick={() => {
      field.handleClick();
    }}
  />;
};

const component = (props: { dismiss: Function }) => {
  <Field
    name="Test"
    component={Range}
    props={{handleClick:() => props.dismiss()}}
    label="Test"
  />;
};
```